# How to convert calculated SQL column to 2 decimal place?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT order_id, ROUND(10,2 (quantity * list_price) * (1-discount)) AS total_price 
FROM order_items;
```

I am trying to round the total_price column to 2 decimal places but it is throwing me an error.

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of decimal places of precision is the *second* parameter to `ROUND`:

```
SELECT
    order_id,
    ROUND((quantity * list_price) * (1-discount), 2) AS total_price 
FROM order_items;
```

Answer (score 0):

syntax is ROUND (number, decimal , operation)
Try

```sql
SELECT order_id, ROUND((quantity * list_price) * (1-discount),2,1) AS total_price 
FROM order_items;
```

operation = 1 for round and operation = 0 for truncate.